# Authentication Failed zk Session Timeout Issue

Tags: go, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, session-timeout, zk

I am using **samuel's go-zookeeper** and have been encountering **"Authentication failed: zk: session has been expired by the server"** issue. Once this issue is encountered it does retry to reconnect to zookeeper and also get successfully connected. But the problem is it again gets **"Authentication failed"** issue or fails to register the consumers. Also, if it does get successfully connected and is Authenticated, consumer never consumes the message as **"Currently registered consumers: 0"** and this process continues unless I restart my client manually.

What might be the issue and its solution??

Here is the log:

```
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:49:20 structs.go:21: Recv loop terminated: err=read tcp 10.244.0.9:41810->10.0.30.4:2181: i/o timeout
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:49:24 structs.go:21: Send loop terminated: err=<nil>
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:49:26 structs.go:21: Connected to 10.0.30.4:2181
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:49:53 structs.go:21: Authentication failed: read tcp 10.244.0.9:43854->10.0.30.4:2181: i/o timeout
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:49:57 structs.go:21: Connected to 10.0.30.4:2181
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:50:25 structs.go:21: Authentication failed: read tcp 10.244.0.9:43863->10.0.30.4:2181: i/o timeout
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:50:32 structs.go:21: Connected to 10.0.30.4:2181
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:51:06 structs.go:21: Authentication failed: read tcp 10.244.0.9:43873->10.0.30.4:2181: i/o timeout
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:51:55 structs.go:21: Connected to 10.0.30.4:2181
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:52:08 structs.go:21: Authentication failed: zk: session has been expired by the server
[Sarama] 2016/05/15 04:52:08 [controller/fa956f688354] Triggering rebalance due to consumer list change
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:52:10 structs.go:21: Connected to 10.0.30.4:2181
[Scheduler] 2016/05/15 04:52:10 structs.go:21: Authenticated: id=95829041879007139, timeout=4000
[Sarama] 2016/05/15 04:52:10 [controller/fa956f688354] Currently registered consumers: 0
[Sarama] 2016/05/15 04:52:10 [controller/fa956f688354] topic :: Started topic consumer
[Sarama] 2016/05/15 04:52:10 [controller/fa956f688354] topic :: Stopped topic consumer
[Sarama] 2016/05/15 04:53:22 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker 10.0.30.4:9092
[Sarama] 2016/05/15 05:03:23 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker 10.0.30.4:9092
.
.
.
[Sarama] 2016/05/15 04:53:22 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker 10.0.30.4:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used samuel's go-zookeeper. However, you are trying to connect to kafka server and make a connection with. To achieve this,  I have use [samara](https://shopify.github.io/sarama)  which is easy to use and reliable.

[Here](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#pkg-examples) some examples.

Comment: Yes, we are using sarama as well you can see logs from sarama in above mentioned logs.